# Определение частоты звука wave-файла Python: почему один канал обрабатывается корректно, а второй - практически дублирует на выходе данные первого?

Tags: python-3.x, аудио, numpy, фурье, wav

Всем привет. 
Я пытаюсь получить частоту звука записанного ранее в wav-файл. В этот файл записывались на разные каналы определенные данные.
[здесь нашел часть решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648151/python-frequency-detection) Немного модифицировал, получилось вот что:

```
import wave
import numpy as np

chunk = 2205
# open up a wave
wf = wave.open('test_card.wav', 'r')
swidth = wf.getsampwidth()
num_channels = wf.getnchannels()
RATE = wf.getframerate()
# use a Blackman window
window = np.blackman(chunk)
# open stream

# read some data
data = wf.readframes(chunk)
data_x = data[0:len(data):2]
data_y = data[1:len(data):2]
# play stream and find the frequency of each chunk
print(len(data_x))
print(data_x)
print(data_y)
while len(data_x) == chunk*swidth and len(data_y) == chunk*swidth:
    # write data out to the audio stream
    # unpack the data and times by the hamming window
    indata_x = np.array(wave.struct.unpack("%dh" % (len(data_x) / swidth), data_x)) * window
    indata_y = np.array(wave.struct.unpack("%dh" % (len(data_y) / swidth), data_y)) * window
    # Take the fft and square each value
    fftData_x = abs(np.fft.rfft(indata_x)) ** 2
    fftData_y = abs(np.fft.rfft(indata_y)) ** 2
    # find the maximum
    which_x = fftData_x[1:].argmax() + 1
    which_y = fftData_y[1:].argmax() + 1
    # use quadratic interpolation around the max
    if which_x != len(fftData_x)-1:
        y0x, y1x, y2x = np.log(fftData_x[which_x - 1:which_x + 2:])
        x1x = (y2x - y0x) * .5 / (2 * y1x - y2x - y0x)
        # find the frequency and output it
        x = (which_x + x1x) * RATE / chunk
        print("The X is %f Hz." % (x))
    else:
        x = which_x * RATE / chunk
        print("The X freq is %f Hz." % (x))
    if which_y != len(fftData_y) - 1:
        y0y, y1y, y2y = np.log(fftData_y[which_y - 1:which_y + 2:])
        x1y = (y2y - y0y) * .5 / (2 * y1y - y2y - y0y)
        # find the frequency and output it
        y = (which_y + x1y) * RATE / chunk
        print("The Y is %f Hz." % (y))
    else:
        x = which_x * RATE / chunk
        print("The Y freq is %f Hz." % (y))
    # read some more data
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)
    data_x = data[0:len(data):2]
    data_y = data[1:len(data):2]
```

Код, конечно, не оптимизирован, так как предполагалось пока только попробовать как извелкуться данные.

Но, почему то, значения X и Y почти совпадают по значениям, хотя пишутся на разные каналы абсолютно разные данные.

Для преобразования амплитуды из wav-файла в частоту звука использовалось Быстро е преобразование Фурье (которых довольно много в модуле numpy), может я не так его использовал?

Пример вывода:
The X is 3423.619376 Hz.
The Y is 3423.562192 Hz.

Но X тут должен быть около 2100 Гц.
Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем у меня может быть ошибка?

Comment: К сожалению, первый вариант не подходит - scipy тянет много зависимостей и нет нормального билда для винды (увы, под винду писать приходится), да и аудио там рассматривается одноканальное, а у меня 2-х канальные. Да и вопрос не в том, как получить частоту в принципе, а как правильно считать её из разных каналов аудио-фала. Частоту я получить смог, но, по сути, только половину.

Comment: В любом случае - не о нем тут речь. Речь  в правильном разложении wav-файла по каналам. вы б хоть код глянули. Опыта, судя по всему, у вас больше чем у меня

Comment: Дружище, не разводи полемику. Ты код посмотрел? Да, или нет? так вот... Я корректно разделяю wav на каналы. (могу хоть на 4 разделить, если будет четырехканальный). Вопрос в том, почему один канал обрабатывается корректно, а второй - практически дублирует на выходе данные первого канала? Можешь помочь? так покажи в какой строчки я ошибся и почему, а не доказывай, что я неверно вопрос задал. Знаешь ли, для меня задавать вопросы на форуме - последнее средство.